# npm install couchbase on linux machine failing

Tags: linux, node.js, npm, couchbase

I am trying to move node js application from windows machine to linux machine for QA environment and I am having trouble installing couchbase module on linux machine.

It ran fine on windows machine but I've tried this install on 4 different linux machine and I get this error message  when I run

> npm install couchbase --no-bin-links

I am on precise32 with vagrant for this logs.

```
 couchbase@2.1.3 install /vagrant/MBO 2122016/node_modules/couchbase
 prebuild --install

sh: 1: prebuild: not found
npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae
npm ERR! argv "/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v5.3.0/bin/node" "/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v5.3.0/bin/npm" "install" "couchbase" "--no-bin-links"
npm ERR! node v5.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! couchbase@2.1.3 install: `prebuild --install`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the couchbase@2.1.3 install script 'prebuild --install'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the couchbase package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     prebuild --install
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls couchbase
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae
npm ERR! argv "/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v5.3.0/bin/node" "/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v5.3.0/bin/npm" "install" "couchbase" "--no-bin-links"
npm ERR! node v5.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.6258c2ba9fb733156e17534450091eff
npm ERR! code ETXTBSY
npm ERR! errno -26
npm ERR! syscall rename
```

I have posted npm-debug I got from this command to pastebin

> http://pastebin.com/TtPFCSYf

Comment: Not a programming question; belongs to either **Super User** or **Unix & Linux** ...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install it with `--no-bin-links` on clean environment, because it relies on `prebuild` binary being accessible. To workaround it, you have to either remove this switch at all, or install prebuild before couchbase without it:

```
npm install prebuild
npm install couchbase --no-bin-links
```